# Hosting sites on wamp server on internet without port suffix

Tags: apache-http-server, iis, wamp, iis-8

We have IIS and Wampserver hosted on the same machine. I have created php based CMS website and hosted using wampserver by changing the default port (in this case from 80 to 81) which is now live to public on internet. Due to hosting IIS and Wamp on the same machine how can i configure the site hosted on wampserver without having to put suffix of port number

currently www.example.com:81 would like to achieve www.example.com

Can someone help please..

Answer (score 1):

@vamcy - thinking a bit more, you could use virtualhost containers alongside modproxy to have Apache relay some domains/urls on to IIS while handling others.

Answer (score 0):

If have write acces on the DNS for your `example.com`, add this SRV record:

`_http._tcp.www.example.com 86400 IN SRV 0 33 81 www.example.com`

Obviously, replace `www.example.com` by whatever your domain name is.

Comment: What kind of support is there for SRV records in browsers - my understanding is that its pretty non-existant (but good on you for suggesting at least a partial solution to an impossible problem)

Comment: Thank you @Nathan Shiraini but it doesn't seem working though. I have created SRV record at godaddy (domain hosting provider). Website is published on in house server.

Comment: @davidgo is that means hosting websites on IIS and wamp on a same server is not possible without having to use port number in the url? sorry if thats a dumb question to ask.

Comment: The other option, still with DNS, would be a NAPTR record, although I'm unfamiliar with it. It allows you to redirect a domain name to a full URL, including port number. However, it is impossible, by design, to have two *different* programs listening to connections on the *same* port, because otherwise the system won't know which program the connections are addressed to.

Comment: @vamcy - correct. I do notevthis has nothing to do with IIS though, the limitation is lack of browser support.

Comment: @NathanShiraini - naptr records wont help you any more then srv recordsv- there is no browser support for them.

Comment: @davidgo That seems strange that browsers don't support `NAPTR`...  AFAIK when these records are used, there is no `A`or `CNAME` records for the domain they are related to. That would mean (sub)domains recorded in `NAPTR` can't be reached by browsers?

Comment: I don't think NAPR was designed with browsers in mind - from what I have seen its more for SIP systems.  It looks like a security minefield to me.  Also, I think implementing it would be hard as it would seem to me to require interplay between DNS resolution (done by the OS) and the web server as well as with the client.  For example, how would the web server know which virtual host is being referred to ? (This is normally specified as part of the browser request)